# Echo the STDIN given to a PHP script

Tags: php, json, stdin

I'm trying to use PHP for a command-line script. I pass in a json string to it, and I'm trying to read the values out but getting an error when I do `echo $user_inputs["foo"];`, why is this? Am I forgetting something about json_decode, or is it about using STDIN?

**my_test.php**

```
// Get the STDIN.
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

// Initialize user_inputs_json which will be the entire stdin.
$user_inputs_json = "";

// Read all of stdin.
while($line = fgets($stdin)) {
  $user_inputs_json .= $line;
}

// Create the decoded json object.
$user_inputs = json_decode($user_inputs_json);

// Try to echo a value. This is where I get my error (written out below).
echo $user_inputs["foo"];

fclose($stdin);
```

**Run this in command line to pass JSON into it:**

`$ echo '{"foo":"hello world!", "bar": "goodnight moon!"}' | php my_test.php`

**I get this error:**

`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Users/don/Desktop/my_test.php on line 20`

Comment: `$user_inputs->foo` should do the trick in this case. no?

Comment: Let me remove that negative vote for you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default json_decode converts JSON string into PHP object. If you want to get PHP array, use the second parameter of json_decode:

```
$user_inputs_array = json_decode($user_inputs_json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to always handle the passed in JSON as an array, set the second `json_decode` parameter to true to force it to decode as an array:

```
$user_inputs = json_decode($user_inputs_json, 1);
```